# Activity does not start from notification if its in foreground

Tags: android

I have an app with 2 activities int the sequence say A->B and a service S that is started by A when the app is started. Now on a particular condition this service triggers a notification which should start activity B within my app and with the arguments that B usually needs from A or the Service.

If the notification triggers in A or outside the app it starts B perfectly, but if its triggers in B, it does not recreate B with the new arguments. onCreate method does not run in this case.

Any ideas how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your activity can receive intents without recreating itself. When your B activity is already running and receives an intent it skips `onCreate(Bundle)` and goes to `onNewIntent(Intent)`. See [`Activity#onNewIntent(Intent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) for details.

What you want to do is setup your methods inside activity B like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  handleNewIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
  super.onNewIntent(intent);

  handleNewIntent(intent);
}

protected void handleNewIntent(Intent intent) {
  // TODO Put intent specific code here
}
```